# How to store JSON or Nested types in JanusGraph?

Tags: janusgraph

What is the recommended approach to store JSON or nested type as a property of a vertex? Should it be converted to a string and stored ? Or, Should a separate vertex be created and the JSON contents should be added as properties? Or, Is there a way to directly store the JSON?

JanusGraph currently supports only the following types:
http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/schema.html#_property_key_data_type

Comment: It really depends on how you plan to use the JSON data. Are you planning on using the keys/values in the JSON as part of your Gremlin queries?

Comment: @JasonPlurad No, we are not going to use it that way. We just want to store it and get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in storing the JSON and do not expect to use its contents as part of a Gremlin query, your best bet is to serialize the JSON into a `String` and store it as a vertex property. I don't see any advantage to creating a separate vertex to store the JSON.

Comment: If we want to use the JSON contents in the gremlin query, should we be creating a vertex and make the JSON contents as key value pairs? This becomes problematic when if we have a highly nested JSON.

Comment: I was suggesting that the entire JSON object is stored as a single property in `String` format. For example `g.addV('person').property('json', '{"name": "jason", "handle": "pluradj", "year": 2018}').next();`. If you do want to use the JSON contents in a query, yes, you likely should consider breaking out sub-objects into separate vertices. Model the graph based on your expected query patterns.